# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Physical Fitness Stack Exchange](http://fitness.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Muscular tiredness from biking -- is it endurance related?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/20922/muscular-tiredness-from-biking-is-it-endurance-related)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [For burning fat, is it better to jog for 45 minutes straight, or break them up by 15 minutes, three times a day?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/20980/for-burning-fat-is-it-better-to-jog-for-45-minutes-straight-or-break-them-up-b)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why does Dmitry Klokov stagger his feet?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/20995/why-does-dmitry-klokov-stagger-his-feet)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can doing the same kind of exercise workout daily provide any good improvements?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/20900/can-doing-the-same-kind-of-exercise-workout-daily-provide-any-good-improvements)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Will doing a large amount of shoulder presses interspersed throughout the day improve strength?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/21067/will-doing-a-large-amount-of-shoulder-presses-interspersed-throughout-the-day-im)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are the advantages and disadvantages to doing higher rep squats?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/20931/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-to-doing-higher-rep-squats)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is a mainly cardio based schedule any good?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/20885/is-a-mainly-cardio-based-schedule-any-good)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [taking creatine in line with take a diureic](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/21083/taking-creatine-in-line-with-take-a-diureic)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Toenail removed - realistically, how long before I can start running again?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22161/toenail-removed-realistically-how-long-before-i-can-start-running-again)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [When a muscle can flex so tight it's painful, is anything wrong?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/20911/when-a-muscle-can-flex-so-tight-its-painful-is-anything-wrong)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Answer (score 2):

I've been spending more time on here (for better or worse), and I find two types of questions that are particularly beneficial:

1. Broad, straight forward, and nearly universally applicable Q&A's. [The historical ones are easy to find](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent), but every now and then a possible will-be-awesome-and-loved-by-many question will materialize.
2. Really specific questions that although not applicable to a large audience, will be extremely useful to someone with that exact problem. [Shameless self plug](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19201/how-can-the-conventional-deadlift-be-harder-at-the-top-than-the-bottom/19206).

What I've been trying to do is be quick not only to downvote/vote-to-close bad questions, but also to upvote good ones and hopefully encourage new people to show up. Especially when an obvious master in the field shows up out of the blue and writes 9 well written paragraphs. I'd love to send those people stackexchange coffee mugs if I could.

I'm still getting the hang out of this place, but it seems like chopping down the bad questions should be practiced as often as group hugs towards the good ones. We should have a reputation for being critical without necessarily just being a bunch of critics.